# Unattended IIS installation on Windows 7 64bit Ent

Tags: iis-7, installation, windows-7-x64

Tried different approached but no luck. Can anyone point me in the right direction with e.g. pkgmgr - the examples I've found doesn't work on 64bit, even when I change to the correct version number and processor architecture.

Thanks

Comment: What does the pkgmgr /L report back?

Comment: I get a 'Operation failed with 0x80070057. The parameter is incorrect'

Comment: Post the XML unattend file to get an answer.